# Shell loop syntax inside makefile if/else

Tags: linux, shell, makefile, gnu-make, gnu

i've loop which I need to add to it `if else` statment,
if the value ==`app1` print x else print y

I've tried with the following
but when I add the `else` I got syntax error,

what am I doing wrong?

```
runners:
    @for a in $(apps) ; do
       if (( a ==  "app1"));then
        echo first: $$v ;
       else
        echo second: $$v ;
        fi
     done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use simply the wrong syntax for `sh` if/else. And you have to add a `\` at each end of the command as all that run as a single command in the shell started by make. Attention: No whitespace after `\` !

It should be something like:

```
runners:
    @for a in $(apps) ; do \
        if [ $$a = "app1" ]; then\
        echo first: $$a ; \
        else \
        echo second: $$a ; \
        fi \
    done
```

BTW: Do you really want to print `$v`? I would expect `$a` instead ;)

Comment: You should prefer `=` not `==` in your if-statement.  The former is POSIX standard, the latter is a bash extension and make invokes `/bin/sh` not `/bin/bash`.

Comment: @MadScientist: Interesting, because both seems to work. I tested both...

Comment: That probably means you're using a system where /bin/sh points to /bin/bash.  Many other systems don't use bash as /bin/sh, they use dash or similar.  For example on an Ubuntu system you'll see: `/bin/sh -c '[ 1 == 2 ] && echo nope'` gives `/bin/sh: 1: [: unexpected operator`.  If you change to `=` then it works.

Answer (score 5):

1. I prefer to use bash as my shell, because I'm used to it. Therefore I use [`SHELL:=/bin/bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html#index-environment_002c-SHELL-in) at the top of my makefiles. But then your whole makefile fails when a system doesn't provide /bin/bash..
2. If you want to use the same shell for all the lines in a recipe, you can use the special target [`.ONESHELL`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html#index-_002eONESHELL_002c-use-of) This prevents you from using `;\` after every line with no whitespace behind (error prone). But if you use `.ONESHELL` then this is true for ALL recipes in your makefile (which I use, but you may not want).
3. If `runners` is not a file (and it seems like it, because you do not create a file in the recipe), I would recommend making it [`.PHONY`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html). Your version might prevent make from executing it, when there happens to be a file named runners while phony targets are always executed.
4. Double parentheses `((...))` are used for arithmetic expansion. It simply cannot compare strings. Use single or double brackets. See [this great post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/306115/260139).
5. I also think you wanted to print `a` and therefore substituted `$$v` with `$$a`.

So in total, this works perfectly fine as long as you have /bin/bash:

```
SHELL:=/bin/bash
.ONESHELL:
.PHONY: runners
apps:=app2 app3 app1 app5
runners:
    @for a in $(apps) ; do  <<-- ; between commands as usual
      if [[ "$$a" ==  "app1" ]]; then
        echo first: $$a  <<-- no need for ; because of .ONESHELL
      else
        echo second: $$a
      fi
    done
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> second: app2
> second: app3
> first: app1
> second: app5
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Makefile:

```
apps=app1 app2

runners:
    @for a in $(apps) ; do \
        if [ $$a = "app1" ]; then \
            echo "first: $$a" ; \
        else \
            echo "second: $$a" ; \
        fi \
    done
```

which prints

> first: app1
>   second: app2

Comment: Why I see a copy of my answer here ;)

Comment: Possibly because we posted the (easy) answer almost at the same time :) ? Does this sound a good explanation to you? And, watching the answer times, I see mine is older...

Answer (score 0):

Take care: the solutions above are working in a recent "make" version (probably >4) only.
OSX for example includes Gnu make 3.81. So you would need to install a newer make using Homebrew

```
brew reinstall make --with-default-names
```